# Trying to install ruby 1.9.3 with rbenv but keep getting ruby 1.8

Tags: ruby, version, rbenv

Here is a list of commands that I have run to try and install ruby 1.9.3-p0 with rbenv but every time I run `ruby --version` I get 1.8.23. I'm not sure why this is?

```
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p0
Downloading yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b
Installing yaml-0.1.4...
Installed yaml-0.1.4 to /Users/anderskitson/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0

Downloading ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/8e2fef56185cfbaf29d0c8329fc77c05
Installing ruby-1.9.3-p0...
Installed ruby-1.9.3-p0 to /Users/anderskitson/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0

Downloading rubygems-1.8.23.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/178b0ebae78dbb46963c51ad29bb6bd9
Installing rubygems-1.8.23...
Installed rubygems-1.8.23 to /Users/anderskitson/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0

Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p0
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$ rbenv version
1.9.3-p0 (set by /Users/anderskitson/.rbenv/version)
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$
```

**UPDATE**

I get this out put for rbenv global

```
Anderss-MacBook-Pro:anchor anderskitson$ $ rbenv global 1.9.3-p0
-bash: $: command not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the ruby version you wish your shell to use with `rbenv global` after installing the ruby version with rbenv.

```
$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p0
```

See [these docs](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/#rbenv-global) for more.

Comment: Did you by chance copy over the `$` sign in front? This is just used here to denote that this is a statement to be run in the console.